# How to find nearest element in nested array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Suppose i have an array of objects like

```
let strokeArray = [
    {
        id:1234,
        data: [
            [101,122],
            [105,124],
            [107,127],
            [109,129],
        ]
    },
    {
        id:5678,
        data: [
            [201,522],
            [205,524],
            [207,527],
            [209,529],
        ]
    },
    {
        id:0001,
        data: [
            [601,622],
            [205,595],
            [607,627],
            [609,629],
        ]
    }
]
```

And i have array of point `[x,y]` say `[202,523]`. This needs to be compared with **data**

I want to find which array element in **strokeArray** contains the nearest value to the above point.

In the above case the answer is strokeArray[1] because it has the nearest coordinates inside the data.

Also i need some boundary conditions to search.

- for example the point `[300,600]` should return empty, because its nowhere close to any data.
- If exact match is found we need that instance, for example `[205,595]` must return strokeArray[2]. Since it has exact match.

What i tried is

```
strokeArray.forEach((stroke) => {
      stroke.data.forEach((coordinate, index) => {
        if(coordinate === [205,595]){return index}
        // But this only checks exach match
      });
});
```

Can someone help me in achieving this.

Comment: why do you want an empty result, if you seach for the nearest in other cases? should some of the two values match?

Comment: Is this data static, or is it updated during the session? I mean can items be added/removed?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for spending time reading my requirement. This is for mobile app, Actually the data which you see above is for 3 strokes. Im trying to delete the stroke which user taps. since there may be plus or minus 2 points, i need the nearest stroke. But if user taps somewhere away means i dont need the nearest stroke. Hope you got what i mean.

Comment: nearest is like equal ?

Comment: @Teemu the data will be populated when user draws each stroke. Once added it cannot be modified. so its kind of static only. Thanks!

Comment: You must define what means 'nearest'... in a point system means the distance from x-y coordinate in module i think...

So you can check |x-xCheck| + |y-yCheck| that is close to 0 inside a RANGE that you must define (ex: 10)... if exist => return index, so return NULL

Comment: @user2149361 Yeah if equal means i need that instance, But if some closest point means i need that instance.

Comment: by what algorithm should the nearest be found?

Comment: @fefoweb Yeah I understand. I need x to be in range of x+3 or x-3 in same way y to be in range of y+3 or y-3. But if the exact match is found that needs to be returned,

Comment: What if there are more than one data point matching the condition? Should only the first found be returned?

Comment: Yeah if more than one meets the condition, the data which has closest one to x,y has to be returned

Comment: @Syed add the exact match in the algoritm :), so check:
- nearest point
- exact match
- empty match

Comment: And when the there are two or more equally closest, the result is lottery, i.e. the first found index, or an array of indices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a plain point-to-point distance calculation.

The math behind is

`d = sqrt(A^2 + B^2)`
where `d`  is the distance on a cartesian space between point A and point B.

In the case of a 2D place, with A(*xA*, *yA*) and B(*xB*, *yB*) the forumala become:

`d = sqrt((xA-XB)^2 + (yA-yB)^2)`

for the sentence *because its nowhere close to any data* I added a configurable threshold logic, so that you can discard points that are more far than a certain value.

```js
let strokeArray = [
    {
        id:1234,
        data: [
            [101,122],
            [105,124],
            [107,127],
            [109,129],
        ]
    },
    {
        id:5678,
        data: [
            [201,522],
            [205,524],
            [207,527],
            [209,529],
        ]
    },
    {
        id:0001,
        data: [
            [601,622],
            [205,595],
            [607,627],
            [609,629],
        ]
    }
];

function calcDistance(a,b){
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a[0]-b[0], 2) + Math.pow(a[1]-b[1],2));
}

function nearestStroke(strokeArray, point, threshold){
  var minDistances = strokeArray.map((stroke, index) => {
    var distances = stroke.data.map((coordinate) => calcDistance(coordinate, point));
    return Math.min.apply(this, distances);
    });
  var min = Math.min.apply(this, minDistances);
  return min < threshold ? strokeArray[minDistances.indexOf(min)] : null;  
}

console.log(nearestStroke(strokeArray, [105,122], 100))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is exactly what i needed.!

Answer (score 2):

You could find the nearest by taking the delta of the hypotenuse.

If data is far away, you could remove the closest index.

This approach returns the index of the given data.

```js
function find(array, coordinates) {
    const
        getDelta = c => c.map((v, i) => v - coordinates[i]),
        map = array.reduce(
            (m, { data }, i) => data.reduce((n, c) => n.set(c, i), m),
            new Map
        ),
        c = [...map.keys()].reduce((a, b) => Math.hypot(...getDelta(a)) < Math.hypot(...getDelta(b))
            ? a
            : b
        );
    return map.get(c);
}

let strokeArray = [{ id: 1234, data: [[101, 122], [105, 124], [107, 127], [109, 129]] }, { id: 5678, data: [[201, 522], [205, 524], [207, 527], [209, 529]] }, { id: 0001, data: [[601, 622], [205, 595], [607, 627], [609, 629]] }];

console.log(find(strokeArray, [202, 523])); // strokeArray[1]
console.log(find(strokeArray, [300, 600])); // []
console.log(find(strokeArray, [205, 595])); // strokeArray[2]
```

Comment: This finds the nearest stroke but if coordinates are far away also finds the nearest one. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am checking if the difference between the X and Y coordinates is lesser than the previous matched loop. Also, I am storing the least difference(threshold of 2) result index and the stroke array Index. We could also compute the nearest for either x or y coordinates.

Also, I am storing closest potential matches (within threshold) in an Object array

```js
let strokeArray = [{
    id: 1234,
    data: [
      [101, 122],
      [105, 124],
      [107, 127],
      [109, 129],
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    data: [
      [201, 522],
      [205, 597],
      [207, 527],
      [210, 523],
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 0001,
    data: [
      [601, 622],
      [205, 595],
      [607, 627],
      [206, 594],
    ]
  }
]
const [matchX, matchY] = [205, 595] //deserialized values to be matched
var diffX = 0;
var diffY = 0;
var prevX = 2;
var prevY = 2;
var innerIndex = 0;
var outerIndex = 0;
var resultArray = new Array;
var closestMatchesArray = new Array;
strokeArray.forEach((stroke, i) => {
  stroke.data.forEach(([coordinateX, coordinateY], index) => {

    diffX = Math.abs(coordinateX - matchX);
    diffY = Math.abs(coordinateY - matchY);
    if (diffX <= prevX && diffY <= prevY) {
      prevX = diffX;
      prevY = diffY;
      closestMatchesArray.push({
        matchOuterIndex: i,
        matchInnerIndex: index,
        matchArray: [coordinateX, coordinateY]
      })
      innerIndex = index;
      outerIndex = i;
      resultArray = [coordinateX, coordinateY];
    } else if (diffX < 2 && diffY < 2) {
      closestMatchesArray.push({
        matchOuterIndex: i,
        matchInnerIndex: index,
        matchArray: [coordinateX, coordinateY]
      })
    }
  });
});
console.log("Inner Index:" + innerIndex); //Matched array Index
console.log("Outer Index:" + outerIndex); //stroke Array Indexs
console.log("Closest Match:" + resultArray);
console.log("closest matches:" + JSON.stringify(closestMatchesArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution:

```
function getThatPoint(x: number, y: number, strokeData: any) {
  const rawCalcs = [].concat(...strokeData.map((sd: any) => {
    return sd.data.map((r: any) => {
      return { strokeId: sd.id, areaIndex: sd.data.indexOf(r), areaX: r[0], areaY: r[1], targetX: x, targetY: y, distance: Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r[0] - x, 2) + Math.pow(r[1] - y, 2)) };
    });
  })) as any[];
  return rawCalcs.filter(x => x.distance === Math.min(...rawCalcs.map((rc: any) => {
    return rc.distance;
  })))[0];
}
```